# Why does my MVCContrib Grid sorting code not work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mvccontrib-grid

For some reason I cannot get my MVCContrib Grid sort to work.

**Why does the following code results in a grid but without the sortable columns?**

I'm using MVC3 and Razor syntax.

```
@model List<InboundShipmentItem>

@using MvcContrib.UI.Grid
@Html.Grid(Model).Sort((GridSortOptions)ViewBag.SortOptions).Columns(column =>
    {
        column.For(item => !item.Verified ? Ajax.ActionLink("Receive", "ReceiveItem", new {id = @item.Id},
                                                            new AjaxOptions
                                                                {
                                                                    HttpMethod = "GET",
                                                                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                                                    UpdateTargetId = "grid",
                                                                    OnSuccess = "InboundShipmentVerification.ReceiveItemSucceeded",
                                                                    OnFailure = "InboundShipmentVerification.ReceiveItemFailed"
                                                                }).ToString() : "Received").Named("Received?").Encode(false);
        column.For(item => item.PONumber).Named("PO#").Sortable(true);
        column.For(item => item.ShipQty).Named("Qty Sent").Sortable(true).SortColumnName("Qty");
        column.For(item => item.ReceivedQty).Named("Qty Recd");
        column.For(item => item.ISBN).Named("ISBN");
        column.For(item => item.Title).Named("Title");
        column.For(item => item.Author).Named("Author");
        column.For(item => item.InboundShipment.Status).Named("Shipment Status");
        column.For(item => item.InboundShipment.ShipmentId).Named("Shipment #");
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that **ViewBag.SortOptions was NULL**.  So if the GridSortOptions object is null the grid does not render any sort links for the header columns.  To me this is silly behavior.

Answer (score 4):

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(column =>
{
////
}).Sort((GridSortOptions)ViewData["sort"])
```

You must fill that ViewData in your Controller.

Like that

```
public ActionResult Index(GridSortOptions sort, int? page)
{
   ///
   ///FILL YOUR MODEL 
   ///IEnumerable<YourModel> list = YourData.ToList() as IEnumerable<YourModel>;

    if (sort.Column == null)
    {
        sort.Column = "DefaultSortColumnName";
        sort.Direction = MvcContrib.Sorting.SortDirection.Ascending;
    }

    ViewData["sort"] = sort;

    return View(list);
}
```